# Where does the One Outs anime diverge from the manga?

Tags: one-outs

Today I just finished watching One Outs and I was interested on picking up the manga, but I would like to know if the adaptation is faithful to the manga and from which volume the anime itself ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anime adapts chapter 1–chapter 82 (volume 10) of the manga. While I have not read the manga yet, I've been led to believe that it is reasonably similar to the anime in terms of plot. There should be no problems in starting off from chapter 83.